# From which Apollo mission is this audio sample?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, communication, russia

I found this [page](http://video8.ru/ntv-luna.php) where Evgeny Molotov, former head of the Research institute of Space instruments, plays supposed [intercepted communication of unknown Apollo mission](https://yadi.sk/d/tVjcJEfcXJZVm). Can anyone identify from which Apollo mission that audio sample is?

Comment: "Intercepted" is kind of an odd term to use; there wasn't any particular effort made to secure communications with Apollo AFAIK.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NASA's Lunar Surface Journal collection has annotated transcripts of all the Apollo landing missions, so I just picked out a couple of key phrases from the recording and googled for:

`apollo surface transcript "nothing flat" "reasonable to go"`

Thus, I believe that's [Apollo 12](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a12/a12.posteva1.html), starting at 121:27:45:

> 121:27:45 Conrad: Okay. Now, in looking at the map, we got all the way over to... If you go to, what is it, the general map, map 5, or whatever you want to call them, we got over in that Shelf Crater (Middle Crescent Crater). That's where you sent us, and we got to that fellow, so some of that stuff we picked up might be of that Copernican ray material. We also had photographs down there of that shelf, which everybody thought was interesting. I took a set of stereos in that thing, all the way around that big crater. Now, we made it over there with no strain. Matter of fact, we ran over and ran back in nothing flat. So, I think it's reasonable to go as you have indicated. Which would be one, starting at F, which is right in front of the spacecraft, then going to Sharp, then going to Bench, then to Halo, then to the Surveyor crater, then to Block, and back to the spacecraft. How's that sound?

The recording is of the moon-to-Earth side only (as you would expect in this case); in the transcript, Gibson is the Earth-side CAPCOM, not heard in the recording. (Pete) Conrad is the commander and (Alan) Bean is the LM pilot.

At this point in the mission, they've completed their first EVA on the surface of the moon, and are planning the route for their second EVA and discussing various complications, like water leaking into Conrad's suit and pooling in his boots.

Even without searchable transcripts, the mention of "the Surveyor crater" points to Apollo 12 (they landed a few hundred meters from the site of the unmanned Surveyor 3 landing).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29562108#29562108).